# Using Dashboard APIs or Frameworks using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dashboard, geckoboard

I heard about Dashboard APIs using JavaScript/Jquery, particularly [Geckoboard](http://www.geckoboard.com/) and many others also.

But I don't know how to use it.

I have a Java web application. It is used to collect some data from users and save to database. After that some analysis will be done and display as graphs or some other graphical representations.

The problem is I don't know how to use that for my application.

Do I need to add some Action classes or JQuery/JavaScript.

I tried to add a widget there but it needs a url to the application. Is it with action class URL and does that need to return any JSON data?

Anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Dashy](http://codecanyon.net/item/dashy-powerful-dashboard/9854741) is a simple angularJs script that let you add custom datasource?

**Please note**: I'm the developer of Dashy.